# Intent Android Sharing

Tags: android, share

This is the present code am using.

```
public void share(String subject,String text) {
     final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setType("text/plain");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share)));
}
```

Am sharing the Content using the above code.
But what I required is when user shares something, I need it's Count.
in Ios we achieved it by using

```
UIActivityViewController  shareController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);
shareController.ExcludedActivityTypes = new[] {
                    UIActivityType.Mail,
                    UIActivityType.PostToFacebook,
                    UIActivityType.Message,
                    UIActivityType.PostToTwitter,
                    UIActivityType.AirDrop
                                            };
```

and we got the response as
shareController.CompletionHandler += (NSString arg1, bool arg2)=>
But how we can handle at android.

Comment: means you want to store count for each successful share on any  app like FB ,Gmail ,

Comment: Yes, Exactly chetan

Comment: I think for this you need to create custom Share Chooser and When you chose from any app like Facebook then at that point you can store count for share .

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, post your effort and people will be more likely to come up with helpful advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom chooser android example is like a dialog to show the list of application depends on the your intent.Here,i have written the simple steps to create the simple custom chooser ,Follow the simple steps to do this.

1)Create Intent to perform share or send operation,

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"velmurugan@androidtoppers.com"});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hi");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi,This is Test");

email.setType("text/plain");
```

2)Create AlertDialog to set the Application in the alertdialog,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Custom_chooser.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
WMLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
dialog.show();
```

3)Get the list of application related to the particular intent using the ResolveInfo,

```
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(email, 0);
Collections.sort(launchables,newResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
```

4)Set the list of application to the custom listview.

```
adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

5)Finally,lanch the particular application when choose the application from the list of application in listview,

```
ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
activity.name);
email.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
email.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
email.setComponent(name);
startActivity(email);
```

while you click on List item you know which application you choose to share your content and and here you can count  for that application.